# tcpdump: cksum incorrect

Tags: tcpdump

When I run `tcpdump` on my machine (here I use `1.2.3.4`)

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -n dst host 1.2.3.4 -v
```

roughly 90% of incoming packets have incorrect checksum:

```
cksum 0xc25b (correct), seq 101134607:101136035
cksum 0xc6b8 (incorrect -> 0x1785), seq 101136035:101156027
cksum 0xd1e0 (incorrect -> 0x00ce), seq 101156027:101178875
cksum 0xc6b8 (incorrect -> 0x7f3d), seq 101178875:101198867
cksum 0xa540 (incorrect -> 0xe396), seq 101198867:101210291
cksum 0xc4ec (incorrect -> 0xdd01), seq 101210291:101229823
cksum 0xc980 (correct), seq 101229823:101231251
cksum 0xc124 (incorrect -> 0x8c52), seq 101231251:101249815
cksum 0xaca0 (incorrect -> 0xf190), seq 101249815:101263127
cksum 0x0d39 (correct), seq 101263127:101264555
```

What could be causing this, and how can I investigate further? Also what would be the most reliable way to test my connection?

I suspect the fiber cable I am connected through might be defective

Would for instance testing with UDP be better, because I would see which packets actually get through ?

I left ping running for several hours, but don't see any problem there (0% loss)

Would such problem demonstrate itself with ping packet loss ?

Comment: Try to pcap that traffic and open with wireshark so you will have two different tools to verify the issue

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is simply too broad to answer, and guessing and speculation are off-topic here. We need things like a good network description or diagram, the network device models, and the network device configurations, etc. You can refer to the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) for guidance, then edit your question.

Comment: checksum offload is the number one case of these problems with tcpdump/wireshark/etc.

Comment: As @RickyBeam already pointed out, checksum offload to the NIC is probably the culprit here. Especially since it looks like the SEQ/ACK numbers seem to be reversed between correct and incorrect packets.

Comment: @Mathias Weidner - isn't checksum offload used for outgoing packets only ? I have specifically pointed out, that these incorrect checksums occur on incoming packets. Also, if checksum offload was the reason, wouldn't 100% be incorrect ?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the word "incoming". Just use the advice given in the answer from Zac67 and find the matching properties of the failed packets. You can also compare this to the matching properties of the correct packets.

Answer (score 2):

The TCP checksum is calculated for the TCP header, the payload and the IP pseudo header.

A checksum error often indicates manipulation to the headers without proper checksum recalculation.

A transmission error over a layer-2 protocol using its own checksum like Ethernet is rather unlikely since Ethernet's FCS rarely misses those errors.

Another possibility is damage to the payload inside a layer-3 hop, e.g. failing memory in a router.

The first step in diagnosis is to find the matching property of failed packets/segments - same gateway, same source, same NAT policy, ...